# A way to chart CPU Usage by application using top -u

Tags: jailbreak, cydia, cydia-substrate

I am trying to really diagnose an awful battery consumption issue with my jailbroken iOS device and I believe a random spike in CPUis causing this.  Is there a way to chart/graph out the output from top -u in MobileTerminal so I can analyze to see if anything is causing that spike?

Appreciate the input here or if anyone has another tool. I have used iCleaner Pro to disable tweaks as well as run a semi-restore.  I would like to be able to troubleshoot this without loosing my jailbreak.

Thanks!

Comment: You can use Xcode instruments.

Comment: I wasn't aware you could do that with it being jailbroken! Any tips for examining what could be causing this?

Comment: I suggest you delete everything you installed from the Cydia. Then look at `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons` and `/Library/LaunchDaemons` directories to see is there any non-Apple daemons left apart from Cydia daemon and evasi0n daemon (in case you used their jailbreak tool). iCleaner may disable MobileSubstrate tweaks but it's very easy to develop a tweak without using MobileSubstrate in which case iCleaner will not help. Enable airplane mode, disable location services and then look at battery consumption. If that doesn't help then may be your battery needs to replaced.